# kendo grid popup display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, popup, grid, kendo-ui

MVC4, razor views.  I can open a detail window for a Kendo (Ajax) grid item using a client template and that works.  My problem is that I lose my grid state (sorting/ordering,etc) when I return to the grid.

My thought was to use a popup window to display the grid item detail.  I see how to create a popup edit window, but I only want to display the details without edit capabilities.

I can't seem to create a custom command since I'm using Ajax datasource.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish opening a detail window and not lose my grid state, or popup a details window only, (using razor syntax please).

Thanks

Comment: Probably you lose the grid's state because you reload it. Check your code and see if you really update it again after you close your detail window.

Comment: Kate - The Details view has a submit button that fires my [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Details()
        {        
            return View("Index");
        }
that, yes, does reload the grid.  How else can I do it so it doesn't reload the grid?

Comment: Why do you need to reload it especially if you don't want to edit details? I

Comment: I really don't want to reload it.  The only way I know to bring up the view again is to return View("Index"), which reloads it.  How can go from the Details view to the Index view without reloading it?

Comment: Instead of opening other view try to open it using Ajax in the dialog window, it's pretty easy to do with KendoUi http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html

Comment: This grid is using Ajax so no custom commands for me.  The only way I can think of popping a window open from the grid is to create a js script.  I was hoping to keep this all razor syntax.  Is there another way?

Comment: I don't think if it's possible with razor syntax, because it's server side technology... Why do you avoid using JS?

Comment: Another learning curve for me.  Thanks for your help Kate.  I am going to pursue the window idea. Paul.

Answer (score 0):

A trick is to use an editor template. If you have setup your grid as bound on the type `MyType` :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyType>().Name("my-grid"))
```

you then just have to add in the same view folder a new folder named `EditorTemplates` (if you always don't have one, normally you have one such folder under the `Shared` folder used for the Kendo templates) and put into it the view that you want to display in your popup :

```
@model MyType

<div class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)</div>
<div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</div>
```

and so on...

Comment: Samuel - The edit window still adds "Update" and "Cancel" buttons at the bottom.  Is there any way I can suppress that?

Comment: One trick is to modify these button with javascript (you can use event `Edit` of the grid in order to add a javascript code when the window opens `@Html.Kendo().Grid().Events(e => e.Edit("my-js-function")`) or if this is the single kendo ui window on your page you can add a css code : `.k-window .k-grid-update { display: none; }`.